# Sample data for testing binary linear classificaion code

Tags: classification, sample-data

I am loking for some sample binary data for testing my linear classifiation code. I need a data set where the data is 2d and belongs to either one of two classes. If anyone has such data or any reference for the same, kindly reply. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question would be on-topic at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I have my own dataset which contain 2 categories of data with 2 features each.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28068989/segmentation_mi_kit.zip
Extract this archive and go to 'segmentation_mi_kit/mango_banyan_dataset/'

Alternately if you want something standard to test your algorithm on, have a look at UCI Machine Learning dataset : http://www.ics.uci.edu/~mlearn/

I guess thatz a kind of data you need.